# Edit AST by using visitors in Antlr

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, visitor-pattern

I am new to AntLR and I am struggling to do the following:

What I want to do is after I have parsed a source file (for which I have a valid grammar of course) and I have the AST in memory, to go and change some stuff and then print it back out though the visitor API.

e.g.

```
int foo() {
    y = x ? 1 : 2;
}
```

and turn it into:

```
int foo() {
    if (x) {
       y = 1;
    else {
       y = 2;
    }
}
```

Up to now I have the appropriate grammar to parse such syntax and I have also made some visitor methods that are getting called when I am on the correct position. What baffles me is that during visiting I can't change the text.

Ideally I would like to have something like this:

```
public Void visitTernExpr(SimpleCParser.TernExprContext ctx) { 
  ctx.setText("something");
  return null; 
}
```

and in my Main I would like to have this AST edited by different visitors that each one of them is specialised in something. Like this:

```
ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
SimpleCLexer lexer = new SimpleCLexer(input);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
SimpleCParser parser = new SimpleCParser(tokens);
ProgramContext ctx = parser.program();

MyChecker1 mc1 = new MyChecker1();
mc1.visit(ctx);
MyChecker2 mc2 = new MyChecker2();
mc1.visit(ctx);

ctx.printToFile("myfile");
```

Is there any way of doing those stuff in AntLR or am I on a very wrong direction?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this ANTLR by smashing the AST nodes and links.  You'll have create all the replacement subtree nodes and splice them in place.  Then you'll have to implement the "spit source text" tree walk; I suggest you investigate "string templates" for this purpose.

But ultimately you have to do a lot of work to achieve this effect.  This is because the goal of the ANTLR tool is largely focused around "parsing", which pushes the rest on you.

If what you are want to do is to replace one set of syntax by another, what you really want is a [program transformation system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation).  These are tools that are designed to have all of the above built-in already so you don't have to reinvent it all.  They also usually have source-to-source transformations, which make accomplishing tasks like the one you have shown much, much easier to implement.

To accomplish your example with our DMS program transformation engine, you'd write a transformation rule and then apply it:

```
rule replace_ternary_assignment_by_ifthenelse
   (l: left_hand_side, c: expression, e1: expression, e2: expression):
       statement -> statement
    "\l = \c ? \e1 : \e2;"
=>  " if (\c)  \l = \e1; else \l = \e2 ";
```

DMS parses your code, builds ASTs, find matches for the rewrites, constructs/splices all those replacement nodes for you.  Finally,
DMS has built-in prettyprinters to regenerate the text.  The point
of all this is to let you get on with your task of modifying your
code, rather than creating a whole new engineering job before you can 
do your task.  Read my essay, "Life After Parsing", easily
found by my bio or with a google search for more on this topic.

[If you go to the [DMS wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS_Software_Reengineering_Toolkit), you will amusingly find
the inverse of this transform used as an example].

Answer (score 0):

I would use a listener, and yes you can modify the AST while you are walking through it.

You can create a new instance of the if/else context and then replace the ternary operator context with it. This is posible because you have a reference to the rule parent and an extensive API to handle every rule children.